# LAS2DEM QGIS No Results

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, las, lastools

When I try use LAS2DEM in QGIS, the results are an empty file:

I have followed all setup instructions with the LAStools zip folder (in a C:\ with no spaces or special characters in the path, and set it up in the QGIS processing options).

What am I missing!? Picture below says to use "-force_precision" to fix the elevation issue but when I add that to the additional command line box nothing changes...

[image]

Comment: Did you try '-rescale 0.01 0.01 0.01'? Have you tried using standalone LASTools?

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0):

That is a paid feature, you need a valid key from the developer, read the error.

Comment: The LASTools that aren't free still work, they just introduce, above a certain level of data, diagonal "noise" lines.

Comment: I did not know that thank you.